# Ethereum python mytherwallet

Tags: python, ethereum

```
class MyEtherApi():


    def __init__(self, addr=None, key=None):
        self.addr = addr
        self.key = key
        self.w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://api.myetherapi.com/eth'))

    def get_eth_balance(self):
        return self.w3.eth.getBalance(self.addr)

    def send_eth(self, address, amt, gas):
        tx = Transaction(
            to=address,
            value=Web3.toWei(amt, 'ether'),
            nonce=int(time()),
            gasprice=self.w3.eth.gasPrice,
            startgas=int(gas),
            data=b'',
           )
        tx.sign(self.key)
        raw_tx = rlp.encode(tx)
        signed = self.w3.toHex(raw_tx)
        return self.w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed)
```

Class for send ethereum. send_eth() return txID, but dont send money.
I have wait more 3 hours. Transaction doesnt send. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `nonce` is going to be way too high. The `nonce` for an account starts at 0 and increases each time the account makes a transaction. You can get the correct current `nonce` for an account by calling `eth_getTransactionCount`.

A `nonce` that's too high means the transaction can't be mined. It will hang around in the transaction pool for a while until the `nonce` becomes valid or too much time passes and it's dropped.